# html / css problem

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to achieve the following (for building a form):

```
Name: [        ] *
```

my markup is:

```
<label>Name:</label>
<input type=text name=name>
<span class=validate></span>
```

my css is:

```
label
{
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    float:left;
}
input
{
    float:left;
}
span.validate
{
    display:block;
    background-image:url(img/required.png);
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}
```

the problem: the validate-span is positioned to the very left border instead of right to the textbox. what is wrong?

thanks

Comment: wouldnt you want to use display:inline?

Comment: unquoted attribute values are disgusting - even though html5 allows them

Comment: @anirudh4444 No, then you cannot set the width and height anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `display: block` on your span, so it will automatically go to a new line. You can change it to `inline-block` or float it as well.

Comment: Unless he really needs to have the block display, this is over-complicating things.

Comment: @DanMan Personally I would add the background image to the parent element, which in my case would probably be `li`, but I haven´t seen the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also add `float: left` to your `span.validate`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/8jDjq/

But, that won't look right if you add another set of the elements underneath: http://jsfiddle.net/8jDjq/2/

To fix that, you need to add `clear: both` to `label`: http://jsfiddle.net/8jDjq/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to `float:left` the validate span (or reconsider those `display:block`s, but I guess they're there for a good reason).

Answer (score 1):

Give the span a float:left too.

Answer (score 1):

```
span.validate
{
    display:block;
    background-image:url(img/required.png);
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    float:left;
}
```

U need  **float:left;** for your span